# Punctuation to ensure that both objects are meant

Tags: grammaticality, commas

> In addition, a weak interaction between light
>   and matter in free space renders the observation of many QED effects, like
>   e.g. quadrature squeezing [3] or the phase shift [4{7] of a single emitter,
>   difficult.

How do I have to set the commas, so that it is clear, that both the squeezing and phase shift are observed for single emitter?

Comment: Why would you want to push the most important word to the end of the sentence in the first place? *Renders difficult* is what is in fact being said, right? "... and matter in free space **renders difficult** the observation of ..." You may also want to replace the phrase 'renders difficult' with another verb/ phrasal verb if you like.

Comment: In addition, the observation of many QED effects (for instance quadrature squeezing [3] and the phase shift [4{7] of a single emitter) is rendered difficult by the weak interaction between light and matter in free space.

Comment: You cannot punctuate your way to showing unambiguously that both modify the single emitter. You could use the Saxon genitive instead; it might make it a tad clumsy, but it would be unambiguous: “for instance a single emitter's quadrature squeezing [3] or phase shift [4}7]”. But punctuation alone cannot do it.

Comment: I think it might help your question if you changed ***meant*** to ***understood***.  :)

Comment: _off-topic_, I suggest you use either _like_ or _e.g._, not both. Although it is hard to call it _wrong_, it gives a bit of a double feeling.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with commas. Repeat the preposition.

> In addition, a weak interaction between light and matter in free space renders difficult the observation of many QED effects, such as the quadrature squeezing of or the phase shift of a single emitter.